# How can I avoid covering the safe area on iPhones, but at least change their color?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, safearealayoutguide

I've noticed that some iPhone apps cannot not only stay away from the safe areas on the iPhone, but they also change the background color of the safe areas, whilst not covering the upper status bar info, icons, time, etc.

I can make my background totally cover the entire screen, but then the iOS' top info disappears.

I cannot find how to do this **using only Xcode**. I'm building everything via code, no use of storyboards.

As a bonus would also love to know if I can change the view, or game scene,  coordinates so that 0,0 (lower left) is above the safe area?

This is the code I found via Google, it stays out ofd the top area but not the bottom. Yes, I just threw it in their I have to stay this more.

What I did notice was that even though I stayed out of the top safe area, the iOS's info, icons, etc. did not appear.

```
view.addSubview(imageView)
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
 imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
 imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
```

Comment: are you using constraints ?

Comment: @jawadAli I just edited the OP because I forgot to add the code I tried

Comment: @Caractacus you have a lot of conflicting constraints, especially since you're constraining agains the main view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to try

```
    mview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    mview.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    mview.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    mview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingBelow:view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
    mview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
```

Note: I dont know why your both instances names are same ... "`view`"